# Lazarus comparando Datas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal, lazarus

No coletor de dados posso configurar o formato da Data, mas eu quero fazer essa configuração dentro da minha aplicação, estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'dd-mm-yy';
ShowMessage(QueryTesteDT_PALLET.Text); // Resultado: '06-07-17'
if QueryTesteDT_PALLET.Value <= StrToDate('30-06-17') then
....
```

Estou com o seguinte erro: "30-06-17" is not a valid date format.

Estou utilizando o Lazarus para desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca utilizei Lazarus, porem...

> if QueryTesteDT_PALLET.Value <= StrToDate('30-06-17') then

costumo fazer algo assim:

> if QueryTesteDT_PALLET.AsDate <= 30-06-17 then // ou 30.06.17 ou 30/06/17

Se não tiver uma tipagem "asDate" ou asDateTime.
Pode ser interessante passar tudo para String e usar um **btween**.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve passar o FormatSettings que você ajustou como parâmetro da função StrToDate.
Também é necessário atribuir o separador que você deseja utilizar ao atributo
FormatSettings.DateSeparator.

A função StrToDate possui sobrecarga, então você pode utilizá-la de duas maneiras:

A primeira forma recebe apenas a string e converte para data com o formato ShortDateFormat padrão.
**function StrToDate(const S: string): TDateTime; overload;**

A segunda maneira de utilizar a função, recebe a string a ser convertida e os FormatSettings que devem ser utilizados.
**function StrToDate(const S: string; const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime; overload;**

Segue Exemplo de utilização:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TDateTime;
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
  begin
    FormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
    FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
    Data := StrToDate('01-06-2017', FormatSettings);
    ShowMessage(DateToStr(Data));
end;
```